# How to focus TextInput after component mount ( initialize with the TextInput focused ) - React Native

Tags: react-native

How do I open a stateless component with the TextInput already in foucs?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Túlio here is the code and you can also check the live working example I've added in this link --> [Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@zadu797/shallow-yogurt)

export default function App() {

```
  const focusRef = React.useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {     
    if (focusRef.current) focusRef.current.focus()
  },[focusRef])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TextInput
          placeholder="FirstTextInput"
          returnKeyType="next"
          ref={focusRef}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          style={{padding:10}}
       />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Gives me undefined is not an object (evaluating 'focusRef.current.focus()')

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the TextInput field focused on component mount, then you can use the `autoFocus` prop of a [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autofocus) component
e.g.

```js
<TextInput
   autoFocus={true}
/>
```